# "Syntax error on token "else", delete this token" (Java) > help me :(

Tags: java

I'm trying put if else statement where it will ask the user to put complete info on the text

[Here's the screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzHaJ.png)

```
btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(txtPc.getText().equals("") || txtPn.getText().equals("") || txtPt.getText().equals("") || txtQuant.getText().equals(""));{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up all the informations!");
        }
        else {
        Object[] row = new Object[4];
        row[0] = txtPc.getText();
        row[1] = txtPn.getText();
        row[2] = txtPt.getText();
        row[3] = txtQuant.getText();
        model.addRow(row);
        
        txtPc.setText("");
        txtPn.setText("");
        txtPt.setText("");
        txtQuant.setText("");
        txtPc.requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

i got error on "else".

Comment: You have an extra `;` at the end of your `if` condition, before `{`

Comment: oww thank you so much, i didn't see it. sorry im just to new to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

remove the **;** at the end of the if condition.

syntax

```
if(condition) {
} else {
}
```